# Image.GetScaledInstance() in Java not Working

Tags: java

I run the code below and the image it is getting the scaledInstance from is already appearing, but I am trying to create a smaller version of it.

```
Image tPoke = poke.getScaledInstance(poke.getWidth(null)*2/3,poke.getHeight(null)*2/3,Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
```

After running this code the image returns with a width of `-1;`

Comment: I'd wager that both `Image.getWidth` and `Image.getHeight` returned `-1` because the dimensions were not known yet, in which case this case "If both width and height are negative, then the original image dimensions are used." comes into effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Images are loaded/produced **asynchronously** in Java.

To wait for a `java.awt.Image` to be ready (fully loaded or resized), you can use the `java.awt.MediaTracker`:

```
// load
Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(url);

// resize, internally chains as operation after loading
image = image.getScaledInstance(width, height, Image.SCALE_AREA_AVERAGING);

// wait for image to be ready
MediaTracker tracker = new MediaTracker(new java.awt.Container());
tracker.addImage(image, 0);
try {
    tracker.waitForAll();
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Image loading interrupted", ex);
}
```

That's also why `Image` has an observer argument on `getWidth(..)` and `getHeight()`. Only when it is ready, the width, height and image data are available (until then, the width and height are usually returned as `-1`). Once the image is loaded, you can use `null` as observer and directly get the dimensions.

Comment: Hint for resizing: use `Image.SCALE_SMOOTH` (interpolation) when scaling up, and `Image.SCALE_AREA_AVERAGING` when scaling down

Comment: AWESOME! Thank you so much!

Comment: If it worked, don't forget to «accept» the answer :)